# exercise 5.12 replace by pattern comprehension

Tags: neo4j

Retrieve the movies that have at least 2 directors, and optionally the names of people who reviewed the movies.

```
MATCH (m:Movie)
WITH m, size((:Person)-[:DIRECTED]->(m)) AS directors
WHERE directors >= 2
OPTIONAL MATCH (p:Person)-[:REVIEWED]->(m)
RETURN  m.title, p.name
```

[this is the expected output]
[image: (https://i.stack.imgur.com/0F3iU.png)]

Comment: What have you tried so far? what is the result?

Comment: so what's the problem

Answer (score 0):

Line #3 of below query is a pattern comprehension.

```
MATCH (m:Movie) 
WITH m 
WHERE size ([(p:Person)-[:DIRECTED]->(m)|p]) >= 2
OPTIONAL MATCH (p:Person)-[:REVIEWED]->(m)
RETURN  m.title, p.name
```

Reference: https://neo4j.com/docs/cypher-manual/current/syntax/lists/#cypher-pattern-comprehension